# Theano convolutional_mlp error

Tags: theano

I am a newbie to convolution neural network and theano. So I tried to run the code from the tutorial. But the convolutional_mlp.py ([code link](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/convolutional_mlp.py)) failed with the following error:
Type Error: **init**() got unexpected keyword argument 'input_shape' ([detailed error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHcX5.jpg)). The logistic_sgd.py and mlp.py can be executed without any problem. Does anyone have any idea what is the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which code? You should edit your question and add the problematic code parts.

Comment: It is the original convolutional_mlp.py in the tutorial and error was in conv.py. I have added the detailed error log as attached image. Hopefully it provides enough information.Thank you.

Comment: And I also added the code link.

Comment: This problem has been fixed by modifying line 97 to "image_shape=image_shape". Thanks.